# what could be resulting to this error? Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\view' not found

Tags: laravel

the website was working well on localhost but brought this error on hosting online.
Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\view' not found

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might be cause the difference of language level. Check what PHP version you have on hosting and what is the version on your local machine.

Mainly you should keep convention as it's declared so use class `View` starting from an uppercase.

You maybe using the `view()` function and accidentialy include the `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\view` in some file. Just delete it - it also should  resolve the problem.

Comment: thankyou. i hade used a small v and by changing to View it worked.

Comment: Target class [App\http\controllers\mycontroller] does not exist.

Comment: Paste the code of `MyController`